# Can you help me decipher this audio clip?

Tags: vocabulaire

[Audio clip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y90lNpfO4bBRazRrTx-_a4bjOpEmOGFL/view?usp=sharing)

Hello. I need help understanding one word in particular. It has an f in it, right before "tâter le terrain". It sounds like "frenyeux" or something. What is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is "je ferais mieux de tâter le terrain en discutant avec ses proches".